# How to debug a "silent" crash in a SwiftUI app

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode-debugger

I've been experiencing a "silent" app crash for quite some time now. It's fairly repeatable and happens when transitioning from one screen to another in SwiftUI:

```
ZStack {
    switch(router.currentScreen) {
        case .screenA:
            ScreenA()   
        case .screenB:
            ScreenB()
    }
}
.animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.5), value: router.currentScreen)
```

*Note - it doesn't happen EVERY time when going to screen A to screen B. But when the app does crash, it's always when going from screen A to B, so the issue isn't with the code above - I'm just including that for context. The problem is that there's no breakpoint hit in Xcode, no stack trace, and no output in the console. If I'm running while attached to the debugger I'll get this error:

```
Lost connection to the debugger. Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain Code: 22
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-03-25 19:04:52 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
}
```

If I'm not connected to the debugger, the app just dies like I said. I'm unable to find any record of the crash anywhere so I have no idea why or what code is causing it.

What I've tried:

- Setting the "All Objective-C Exceptions" breakpoint (never gets
  tripped)
- Setting the "All Runtime Issues" breakpoint (never gets
  tripped)
- Xcode -> Devices and Simulators -> Open Recent Logs (no
  relevant logs)
- Xcode -> Devices and Simulators -> Open Console (empty
  for my device)
- Checked Crashlytics. Says I'm 100% crash-free.
- Monitoring Memory in the Xcode Debug Navigator. It
  goes up from around 60 to around 120 MB at this point, but that
  doesn't seem like enough to cause a crash.
- Product -> Analyze ("Succeeded", but no other info)
- Instruments -> Leaks (no leaks detected)
- Texting Tim Cook (no response)

What else can I do to find out why my app is crashing???

Comment: Without knowing that much about your crash, it could sound like a similar problem that I had a while ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73791060/removing-swiftui-navigationview-from-view-hierarchy-result-in-exc-bad-access

Comment: When I get this error it usually means that I am using too much resource of the device (CPU/RAM), so if the apps want to continue it kills the "debugger" to get more resources, but that kill the app then (since you're "detached"). So I'd recommend you to check the CPU/Memory use and check that if it's indeed getting bigger and bigger. Check if there is a memory leak, etc and what you can optimize. So I'd still check the memory and see if it would ask for more (before it crashes and might show you only 120MB, like asking 100 more, but crash before reporting it)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the Address Sanitizer. This can often help identify these strange crashes. You can find it by clicking your scheme on the top bar, and selecting "Edit Scheme".

More information about how to use it can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early

[image: Address Sanitizer]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Running with this on seems to make it crash slightly more often, but I don't get any additional information about the crash.

Comment: That's strange, I would have expected that you saw something. But if you don't even see a stack trance, that's difficult. Is it possible for you to produce a minimal reproducible example?