# How to cancel a task that is running in a view modifier

Tags: swift, swiftui

Consider this code that places fluctuating `CatView`s in a view's `.background` modifier:

```
@State private var catOn = true

...

SomeView()
.background {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        ForEach(0...numCats, id: \.self) { n in
            CatView(color: n%2 == 0 ? color1 : color2, size: 15, isOn: n%2 == 0 ? catOn : !catOn)
            //.frame = ...
        }
        .task {
            while !Task.isCancelled {
                try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1.0))
                catOn.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

The problem is that I think this code is causing a crash sometimes when the view is replaced by another view, perhaps because the task fires during the transition (I don't get the crash when I comment out the `.task`). How can I cancel this task when a button is pushed, before I trigger the property that transitions this view away? Also, is there a better way to set this task up? As you can see, I need the CatViews to swap colors every second.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] that causes a crash? You can easily cancel the task using `task(id: ...)` and setting the id to something else, but I don't know if that will fix the crash, without having a MRE.

Comment: Well, regardless if it's the actual cause of the [crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78221316/how-to-debug-a-silent-crash-in-a-swiftui-app), could you elaborate more on the technique to stop the task?

Comment: Actually, you can just add an additional `@State private var cancelled = false`. Set this to true in the button's action, and in the task, check `if cancelled { return }` to end the task. Does that work?

Comment: @Sweeper would that code go outside and after the while loop? And do I still need the while loop or could I just say if `!cancelled {try? await ... etc}`

Comment: Forget about my second comment. I think using `.task(id:)` is a much better solution than checking `if cancelled { return }` inside the loop. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should catch cancellation errors thrown by `sleep` so that `catOn` is not toggled when the tasks is cancelled during the `sleep`:

```
while !Task.isCancelled {
    do {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1.0))
        catOn.toggle()
    } catch is CancellationError {
        return // the task is cancelled during the sleep
    } catch {
        fatalError("Something unexpected happened")
    }
}
```

The task will still only be cancelled when the view disappears. To cancel the task immediately on demand, you can use the `task(id:)` overload. When this `id` changes, the currently running task is cancelled, and a new task is started. You can `return` immediately when the new `id` is some sentinel value. For example:

```
@State var cancelled = false
@State var catOn = false

var body: some View {
    Toggle("Cat On", isOn: $catOn)
    
    Button("Cancel Task") {
        cancelled = true
    }
    .task(id: cancelled) {
        if cancelled { return }

        while !Task.isCancelled {
            do {
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1.0))
                catOn.toggle()
            } catch is CancellationError {
                return
            } catch {
                fatalError("Something unexpected happened")
            }
        }
    }
}
```